# Update env.js file using powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell

i need to update a url in env.js using powershell can anyone help me in updating the file. below is the snippet of my env.js file

```
function (window) {
    window.__env = window.__env || {};

    // API url
    window.__env.apiUrl = '<updateEnv url here>';



    // Whether or not to enable debug mode
    // Setting this to false will disable console output
    window.__env.enableDebug = true;
  }(this));
```

i need to update window.__env.apiUrl with some url

Thanks

Comment: Where would you get the new value? Editing a text file in Powershell is trivial, so _edit the question_ and explain with more details which part you are having problems with. Loading a file? Replacing the contents? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$filePath = 'C:\myPath\env.js'
$url      = 'http://myurl'

$content = Get-Content $filePath | ForEach-Object { 

    if( $_ -like '*window.__env.apiUrl*' ) {
        $_ -replace '^(.*window\.__env\.apiUrl).*$', ('$1 = ''' + $url + '''')
    }
    else {
        $_
    }
} 
$content | Set-Content -Path $filePath
```